# Angular, verify user from stored email in mySql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, typescript, express

I'm trying to make a simple user verification using email that stored in mySql database and using express JS. The user must enter his/her email first before filling the other form. If the email is not registered/stored in email table, the user will be not able to get the other form. Here is the example of the table in mySql

[image].

```js
//app.js 
//select all email
app.get('/AllEmail', (req, res) => {
  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM email';
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(results);
    var a = JSON.stringify(results);
    res.send(a);
  })
})
```

Now what I need to do is make the client side's typescript recognize the list of email that already stored in table if it is possible. The client side will check which email is `true` and which email is `false`(not stored) from that email table. Here is the client's side using Angular and typescript:

```js
//service.ts
getEmailAPI(): Observable < any > {
  return this.http.get("http://localhost:8000/AllEmail")
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
}

//component.ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.getEmailAPI()
}

Email: string[] = [];
isVerified: boolean = false;
getEmailAPI() {
  this.AppService.getEmailAPI().subscribe(
    data => console.log(this.Email = data),
    error => console.log('server returns error')
  );
}

verifyEmail(formValue) {
  if (this.Email == null) // ||this.email doesn't exist
  {
    this.isVerified = false;
  } else if (this.Email != null) // && this.email exist
  {
    this.isVerified = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--component.html-->
<div class="container" align="center">
  <form ngNativeValidate>
    <label>Please Enter Your Email Below</label>
    <input name="userEmail" type="text" class="form-control" required/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm" (click)="isVerified=!isVerified; verifyEmail()">verify</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isVerified">
  <form>...</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you are fetching the list of all the emails then you should do it like

**Template side :**

```
<div class="container" align="center">
  <form #emailVerification='ngForm' ngNativeValidate (submit)='verifyEmail(emailVerification.value)'>
    <label>Please Enter Your Email Below</label>
    <input name="userEmail" type="text" class="form-control" required ngModel />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm">verify</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Component Side :**

```
isVerified = false;

verifyEmail(formValue) {
    if(this.Email.length > 0) {
        this.Email.every(el => {
            return !(this.isVerified = el.email === formValue.userEmail);
        })
    }
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-verifiaction)**

---

> But I would suggest another way

**Node side**

First make get request to post

```
app.post('/CheckEmail', (req, res) => {
    req.body.email; // get email from client side
    // compare that email with your db entries
    // if it exists return data else null

});
```

**Service Side**

```
getEmailAPI(): Observable < any > {
  return this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/AllEmail",data)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
}
```

**Template side :**

```
verifyEmail(formValue) {
    this.AppService.getEmailAPI().subscribe(
        data => {
            if(data) {
                // do whatever needed is with returned data
                isVerified = true; 
            } else {
                isVerified = false;
            }
        },
        error => console.log('server returns error')
    );
}
```

**Component Side would be same as I put the code above**

Comment: Pardon for my silly question, Mr.Vivek Doshi. I got `Property 'email' doesn't exist in on type string`.

Comment: @WiraXie,Please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-verifiaction?file=app%2Fapp.component.html , it will clear your doubts.

Answer (score 3):

I would review the design of your application, there are serious security issues with this.

Verifying an existing email is one thing, but to be clear, this is not adequate authentication, a proper authentication mechanism should be used instead.

ExpressJS supports various authentication mechanisms:
https://www.google.com.au/search?q=expressjs+authentication&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=XipcWvmEI6Tr8Af49LS4CA

However, if this is not authentication, and is to do a check an email exists in a list, you could do the following.

I would suggest you write an Express service which checks an email and returns true/false, instead of returning ALL emails (privacy issue).

For example (example only):

```
//app.js 
//check email
app.get('/CheckEmail', (req, res) => {
  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM email WHERE email = ?', [req["email"]];
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(results);
    var emailExists = results.length > 0;
    res.send(emailExists);
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Mr. Russell :D